# How to iterate over Option<&Path> with for loop structure?

Tags: rust

I was iterating over a vector of Path references. Now I'm using a crate that instead returns me the `Option<&Path>` type. I've read that `Option` has an iterator. But is there a way to maintain my forloop structure such as:

```
let mut paths: Vec<&Option<&Path>> = vec![];
for i in paths {
...
}
```

Because I need to check if the current iterating path value exists. And I was doing that with:

```
if std::path::Path::new(&i).exists()
```

Obviously `std::path::Path` doesn't satisfy `std::option::Option`.

Is there a way for me to maintain this structure and satisfy the Option type? Particularly, how would I change my if statement to satisfy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need, for each value, to check that it's an `Option::Some`.

Since `Option` is indeed iterable, you can just use this property:

```
for i in paths.into_iter().flatten() {
    ...
}
```

an `Option` is conceptually a collection of 0 or 1 elements, by flattening it you remove the `Option::None` instances, and replace the `Option::Some` by whatever they contain (a Path).

Incidentally, why are you creating a `Path` from a `Path`? You can just check `if i.exists()` since `i` is a `&Path` already.

Answer (score 0):

```
for path in paths {
    if let Some(path) = path {
        if path.exists() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
// `flatten` will turn the iterator of `Option<Path>` to an iterator of `Path`, discarding the `None` values
for path in paths.iter().flatten() {
    if path.exists() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Or:

```
for path in paths.iter().flatten().filter(|p| p.exists()) {
    // ...
}
```